# Configure Tomcat access log in Spring web application via logback xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logback

I am setting up new Spring boot application and currently working on setting the logs configurations

I am using the logback framework and was successful in setting all the application logs via logback.xml file

I need also Tomcat logs : catalina and access logs that will be logged in separate files in custom location

I was able to set the catalina logs successfully via  logback.xml

But for access logs I am able to set it up only via application.yaml but not in logback.xml

I would like that all log configurations will be in one place - logback.xml (easy to maintain) and need help setting it up

What I tried:

This is works via application.yaml:

application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: ****
  servlet:
    context-path: *****
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      prefix: access_log
      suffix: .log
      file-date-format: _yyyy-MM-dd
      directory: logs
      pattern: common
basedir: tomcat
```

logback.xml:

```
<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender" name="FILE-CATALINA">
    <file>${LOGS}/tomcat/catalina.out</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5p: [%c] %m %rEx{20} %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
</root>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
</logger>
```

This is not working via logback.xml:

application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: ****
  servlet:
    context-path: *****
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
```

logback.xml:

```
<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender" name="FILE-CATALINA">
    <file>${LOGS}/tomcat/catalina.out</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5p: [%c] %m %rEx{20} %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender" name="FILE-ACCESS">
    <file>${LOGS}/tomcat/access.out</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5p: [%c] %m %rEx{20} %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ACCESS" />

</root>
<logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-CATALINA" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ACCESS" />
</logger>
```

In this case what I get is catalina logs in access log file as well

Any Help?